# hibernate returned list casting issue

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

Two entity classes:

```
   @Entity
public class FilesInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String url;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="fileId")
    private Collection<FilesShare> filesShared = new ArrayList<FilesShare>();

    public Collection<FilesShare> getFilesShared() {
        return filesShared;
    }

    public void setFilesShared(Collection<FilesShare> filesShared) {
        this.filesShared = filesShared;
    }
```

the second:

```
@Entity
public class FilesShare {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="fileId")
    private Integer fileId;
    private int userId;
    private int owner;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fileId", updatable=false,insertable=false)
    private FilesInfo filesInfo;

    public FilesInfo getFilesInfo() {
        return filesInfo;
    }

    public void setFilesInfo(FilesInfo filesInfo) {
        this.filesInfo = filesInfo;
    }
```

the daoimpl mmethod:

```
public List<FilesInfo> reqSharedFiles(FilesShare fs) {
        session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    List<FilesInfo> filesInfo = null;
            filesInfo=(List<FilesInfo>)session.createQuery("from FilesInfo a, FilesShare b where a.id=b.fileId and b.userId=5 and b.owner=1").list();
```

now i dont understand when hibernate is mapping and returning the object by i am getting this error in action that it cant be casted :

> Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to app.domain.FilesInfo

**The action**

```
private List<FilesInfo> furls= new ArrayList<FilesInfo>();
furls=upload.reqSharedFiles(fs);

                for(FilesInfo s: furls)  // ERROR IS SHOWING HERE
                {
                    System.out.println(s.getUrl());
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou all. Here is what i did after some search.

```
 private List<Object[]> turls=new ArrayList<Object[]>(); //get the list of Object[] from HQL


for(Object[] r : turls)
                {
                    FilesInfo inf =(FilesInfo)r[0];
                    System.out.println(inf.getUrl());
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query does not return a list of `FilesInfo`, but a list of two-element object arrays where the objects are of type `FilesInfo` and `FilesShare`.

You could either rewrite your query so that it only returns a `FilesInfo`, or attach a [`ResultTransformer`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) that pulls out the part you're interested in or constructs an object that you can use to get the info you really want.

Comment: that is understood and i can see the object size as two as it contains 2 results. how can i retrieve now? that for is not working, similarly iterator on filesinfo fail

Answer (score 0):

Your query can result in two diffrent objects,  `from FilesInfo a, FilesShare b`  so if it is a FileShare object it cannot be cast to a FilesInfo

see [hql from](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from)

Comment: see i have one to many and manytoone relaship in those entities and the filter from B table will get the final result from A table. Hope understood

Comment: see the added link in the awnser, it will return multiple classes.

Comment: that is understood and i can see the object size as two as it contains 2 results. how can i retrieve now? that for is not working, similarly iterator on filesinfo fail

Comment: I'd suggest editting the query in to something like this`
`from FilesInfo a  where a.id = (select b.id from FileShare b where b.userId = 5 and b.owner = 1) `

Comment: that gives me "Subquery returns more than 1 row" and ofcourse i want subquery to return multiple results so that i can get multiple rows from table A

Comment: here i have used select a.id,a.name,a.url from FilesInfo a, FilesShare b where a.id=b.fileId and b.userId=5 and b.owner=1, that means a selected columns which match class FilesInfo, still i get that cast error

Comment: When i use IN its giving me only one result :(. I have a doubt now, when the object returned from hql is of multiple type, how it is getting assigned to FilesInfo without giving error?

Comment: it wil save all fileshare relations in your `Collection<FilesShare> filesShared`

Comment: that means its within my FilesInfo object wright? then it should be like a child, instead i think here its like sibling

Comment: I think you do not understand how object oriented query languages work or how the relations work.

many to one example in your domain

If you have a many to one relation ship from FilesInfo to FileShare. You will get a list of all the FileShare that the FilesInfo has a relation with when you have a FilesInfo object returned from a query